# Work with a database in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an app for Android where I need the parameters of focal length (Brennweite) and sensor width (SensorBreite). To use this parameters, I have created a database.

I used "CREATE TABLE smartphones (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Model TEXT,Brennweite FLOAT, SensorBreite FLOAT)" in SQLite Database Browser.

To open the database smartphone.db, the class DatenbankManager copy it from assets to data/data.

```
public class DatenbankManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/de.fovea.waldinvent/databases/";
private static final String DB_NAME = "smartphone.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private final static String SMARTPHONE_TABLE = "smartphones";

private final static String SMARTPHONE_ID = "_id";
private final static String SMARTPHONE_MODEL = "Model";
private final static String SMARTPHONE_BRENNWEITE = "Brennweite";
private final static String SMARTPHONE_SENSORBREITE = "SensorBreite";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
private final Context myContext;

private static final String SMARTPHONE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE smartphones (" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "Model TEXT NOT NULL, " + "Brennweite FLOAT, "+ 
        "SensorBreite FLOAT" +  ")";
    private static final String SMARTPHONE_DROP = 
        "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS smartphones";
    public static final String SMARTPHONE_SELECT_RAW =
        "SELECT _id, Model, Brennweite, SensorBreite FROM smartphones";

public DatenbankManager(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
 * database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        // do nothing - database already exist
    } else {

        // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
        // the default system path
        // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
        // database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
 * time you open the application.
 * 
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {

        // database does't exist yet.

    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
 * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
 * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

    // Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    // Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    // Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SMARTPHONE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(SMARTPHONE_DROP);
    onCreate(db);   }
```

In the activity the model number of the smartphone is saved to a string.

```
String model = android.os.Build.MODEL;
```

Now the App has to find this model string in the database.

```
Cursor c = sqdatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM smartphones WHERE Model = '"+model+"'", null); 
     c.moveToNext();
```

And save column Brennweite in double f and SensorBreite in double B.

Can I do it this way?

Comment: BTW: I would recommend to use english name for database column, database tables, variables etc. It makes more "sense" when reading the code. Also many Germany companies I know have the requirement, that everything in code should be in English, so this isn't a bad habbit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
But I dont think SQLLite has a double datatype, so you will have to do with the Numeric datatype in SQLLite

Answer (score 0):

those are types that you can use in SQLite, CANT use FLOAT when creating the table

**NULL**. The value is a NULL value.
**INTEGER.** The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.
**REAL**. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating point number.
**TEXT**. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
**BLOB**. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.

**use INTEGER instead of FLOAT**

Answer (score 0):

Change your string SMARTPHONE_CREATE to this:

```
private static final String SMARTPHONE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE smartphones (" +
        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "Model TEXT NOT NULL, " + "Brennweite REAL, "+ 
        "SensorBreite REAL" +  ")";
```

Why do yo want `Brenweite` and `SensorBreite` to be float? If there values are in decimal numbers then use REAL otherwise use INTEGER.